# QuickBooks-PHP Import Credit Card Information

Tags: php, quickbooks

I really hope that the author of QuickBooks PHP DevKit will see this post:)

Is there a way to pull stored client's Credit Card information using Client's (QB) ID?

We store CC information in QuickBooks however we use 3rd party payment processing gateway.
So we need to pull CC info of the particular client from QB and pass it to the payment gateway.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Allowing you to do this would be a massive security flaw in QuickBooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to pull stored client's Credit Card information using Client's (QB) ID?

No, QuickBooks does not allow this.

Comment: Thank you, Make sense. Just needed reaffirmation.